# CELERY_ROUTES - how to route based on task name

Tags: celery

I'm trying to get celery to route tasks based on the name of the task... basically, I have tasks that are name 'worker.some_name' and 'web.some_name', and I use two different queues, called worker and web respectively.  I would like all worker tasks to go to the worker queue and vice-versa.  Currently I have a big CELERY_ROUTES dictionary like this:

```
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    "web.some_name": {
        "queue": "web"
    },
    "web.some_other_name": {
        "queue": "web"
    },
    etc.... }
```

But I would like something more generic like:

```
CELERY_ROUTES = (MyRouter(), ) 
class MyRouter(object):
    def route_for_task(self, task, args=None, kwargs=None):
        if task.split('.')[0] == "worker":
            return {"queue": "worker"}
        return {"queue": "web"}
```

But this doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You must have used the decorator "@app.task" for the task you've defined in py file.

You can route your task using @app.task(queue='queue_name')

Comment: This saved my day. Will routings not work if using this decorator?

Comment: It might go to a default queue which celery creates named "celery". Try to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do what you want by changing the exchange type from direct to topic. This way you can specify the tasks as web.* or worker.*

You can read up on it here: http://ask.github.com/celery/userguide/routing.html#topic-exchanges

Comment: That link is dead, heres a good source with all the info Dan mentioned: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#amqp-primer

Comment: Would this work with redis as message broker? I'm not able to get it to work with the manual routing example using wildcards at http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#manual-routing

Answer (score 1):

Wildcard routing is not supported in Celery 3.x by default, but you can implement it yourself.

**Here is a copy-paste solution:**

```
class TaskRouter:
    def __init__(self, routes):
        self.routes = {}
        self.glob_routes = {}

        for glob, queue in routes.items():
            if '*' in glob:
                self.glob_routes[glob] = queue
            else:
                self.routes[glob] = queue

    def route_for_task(self, task, args=None, kwargs=None):
        if task in self.routes:
            return self.routes[task]

        for route in self.glob_routes:
            prefix = route.split('*')[0]
            if task.startswith(prefix):
                return self.glob_routes[route]

        return None # for unknown tasks will be used default queue
```

**Usage:**

```
# celery.py
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'web.*':            'web',
    'web.slow_task':    'slow',
    'worker.*':         'worker',
}

app = Celery('config')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings') # Django or your app config

app.conf.update(
    CELERY_ROUTES=(TaskRouter(CELERY_ROUTES),),
)
```

**How the TaskRouter works:**

```
In [2]: CELERY_ROUTES = { 
   ...:     'web.*':            'web', 
   ...:     'web.slow_task':    'slow', 
   ...:     'worker.*':         'worker', 
   ...: }                                                                       

In [3]: router = TaskRouter(CELERY_ROUTES)                                      

In [4]: router.route_for_task('web.blabla')                                     
Out[4]: 'web'

In [5]: router.route_for_task('web.slow_task')                                  
Out[5]: 'slow'

In [6]: router.route_for_task('unknown_task')  # None = default queue                                 

In [7]: router.route_for_task('worker.foo')                                     
Out[7]: 'worker'

In [8]: router.route_for_task('worker.bar')                                     
Out[8]: 'worker'
```